# NWebsec and URL Rewrite Conflicting

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, webforms, iis-7.5, nwebsec

I have an ASP.NET Webforms application and it is using NWebsec. It works as intended, but I am trying to force HTTPS from the start not after initial request with HSTS. When I add the URL Rewrite it gets in a redirect loop. Removing NWebsec and the URL Rewrite works fine. NWebsec works in either case but without the rewrite if they load HTTP it will not force HTTPS. The `upgrade-insecure-requests` does not work on it's own.

**URL Rewrite Rule**

```
<rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"
redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

**NWebsec Config**

```
<nwebsec>
  <httpHeaderSecurityModule xmlns="http://nwebsec.com/HttpHeaderSecurityModuleConfig.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="NWebsecConfig/HttpHeaderSecurityModuleConfig.xsd">
    <redirectValidation enabled="true" />
      <setNoCacheHttpHeaders enabled="true" />
      <x-Robots-Tag enabled="false" noIndex="false" noFollow="false" noArchive="false" noOdp="false" noSnippet="false" noImageIndex="false" noTranslate="false" />
      <securityHttpHeaders>
        <x-Frame-Options policy="Deny" />
        <strict-Transport-Security max-age="60" includeSubdomains="true" httpsOnly="true" preload="false" />
        <x-Content-Type-Options enabled="true" />
        <x-Download-Options enabled="false" />
        <x-XSS-Protection policy="Disabled" blockMode="true" />
        <content-Security-Policy enabled="true">
          <upgrade-insecure-requests enabled="true"  />
        </content-Security-Policy>
      </securityHttpHeaders>
    </httpHeaderSecurityModule>
</nwebsec>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, PEBKAC. Should have read the [documentation](https://docs.nwebsec.com/en/4.1/nwebsec/Redirect-validation.html) better.

```
<redirectValidation enabled="true">
    <allowSameHostRedirectsToHttps enabled="true" />
</redirectValidation>
```